# Debug or Release mode with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have an Angular app and I'm using Grunt, I made my Gruntfile for min, uglify and concat and after I reference my new .js file (created with Grunt) in my main.html everything is working fine when I publish my project. However, when I want to make some changes and want to run my app in debug mode, I have to change my .js references again in my main.html. Is there a way to check if in what mode my app is running, so I can load the specific .js files? 
I've seen how to accomplish this in ASP.net, but how can I solve it in my case?

Below is my gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
  clean: {
    options: {force: true},
    all: {
        src: ['../Analaysis.UI/app_built/**/*.*']
    }
  },

  ngmin: {
    all: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '../Analaysis.UI',
                src: ['**/*.js'
                    , '!**/Scripts/*'
                    , '!**/Scripts/**/*'
                    , '!**/obj/*'
                    , '!**/obj/**/*'
                    , '!**/src/**/**/*'],
                dest: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
      }
  },

  uglify: {
    all: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built',
                src: ['**/*.js'],
                dest: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        ]
      }
  },

  concat: {
        js: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            },

                src: ['../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/global.min.js'
                    ,'../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/config.min.js'
                    ,'../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/GlobalService.min.js'
                    ,'../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginController.min.js'
                    ,'../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginService.min.js'],
                dest: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/app_built_login.js'

     }
  }
 });

 grunt.registerTask("default", ['build']);
 grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'ngmin', 'uglify', 'concat']);

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean'); 
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ngmin');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```

Comment: use gruntfile with configuration

Comment: @Akhlesh - Could you give me some example or some resource where I could learn more?

Comment: can you show your gruntfile? it would help me to give an appropriate example

Comment: I will post it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each type of build, you would require a different configuration.

Check below code.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

 grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        all: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built',
                    src: ['**/*.js'],
                    dest: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/',
                    ext: '.min.js'
        }
    ]
        },
        prod: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built',
                    src: ['**/*.js'],
                    dest: 'prod/Analaysis.UI/app_built/',//You can have different path according to build type
                    ext: '.min.js'
        }
    ]
        }

    },

    concat: {
        js: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            },

            src: ['../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/global.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/config.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/GlobalService.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginController.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginService.min.js'],
            dest: '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/app_built_login.js'

        },
        prod: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            },

            src: ['../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/global.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/config.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Global/GlobalService.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginController.min.js'
                , '../Analaysis.UI/app_built/Login/LoginService.min.js'],
            dest: 'production/Analaysis.UI/app_built/app_built_login.js'

        }
    }
 });

grunt.registerTask("default", ['build']);
grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify', 'concat']);

//Task according to build. run "grunt debug" for debug build
grunt.registerTask('debug', ['uglify:all', 'concat:js']);
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['uglify:prod', 'concat:prod']);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```

Comment: That's nice, I got this part now. :)
But what about referencing my script in HTML? how can i "switch" references when I'm in debug or release?
I.e. in debug: 
'../Analaysis.UI/app_built/app_built_login.js'
and in release:
'production/Analaysis.UI/app_built/app_built_login.js'

Comment: for that you need to write your custom task that will read your html file and write(change) the respected reference in html file. for more help see grunt docs
http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks and grunt api for reading and writing file